# Embedded Linux- Cross compiling firefox for arm

Tags: linux, embedded, cross-compilation

I am trying to cross compile Firefox (version 39) for Arm. But, I am getting the following error:

```
/firefox-39.0/mozilla-release-849542617a46/build/unix/gold/ld: fatal error
/armv7l-linux-gnueabi/toolchain/lib/crt1.o: unsupported ELF machine number 40
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure: error: couldn't compile a simple C file
```

What should I do ?

Comment: Are you compiling in a virtual? And if so how is it setup?

Comment: No I am not compiling in a virtual.

Comment: Are you compiling on a 64/32 bit machine? If so I have never heard that this is possible without a virtenv

Comment: I using a 32 bit machine. I think we can do it... But I am not sure.

Comment: Sorry yes ofc it's supported but question is how you compile it and with which tool chain. How are you executing the compile

Comment: You need to tell us what you did, not just the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error after I cross-compiled Qt for an iMX6 device. I usually ran a build script from the build directory, and my script assumed that, but this time I forgot, and the build happened in my top level `~/dev` directory. Somehow (I have no idea how), this affected my regular desktop build of Qt, so that any project I built with that desktop build would somehow be affected by the misplaced embedded build.

The fix was to remove the misplaced embedded directories (and add an extra `cd $qtBuildDir` step to my build script ;)).